# AJAX request posting data in body instead of URL concatenation

Tags: javascript, html

I see many websites pursuing their requests through data concatenation in their URL, for example: example.com/api?data=111.

On my website I handle the request in another way, through AJAX:

```
return $.ajax({ url: '../api.php',
                    data: {data: '111'},
                    type: 'post'
    });
```

I was wondering if in my method there is any flaw or if it can be used like the standard method of URL concatenation.

Update for context

```js
function createAJAXRequestToGetCategories() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: '../server.php',
    data: {
      method: 'requestCategories'
    },
    type: 'post'
  });
}
ajaxRequest = createAJAXRequestToGetCategories();
ajaxRequest.done(functionToExecute);
functionToExecute(responseData) {}
```

Comment: Your method is the standard jQuery method - it does however not return the data you expect but a  jqXHR object so the return keyword is not useful .You need a success or complete function

Comment: My api.php does return some data, for example:
`if($_POST["data"] == "111") {
    echo("works!");
}`

Comment: I am doing: `function createAJAXRequestToGetCategories() {
    return $.ajax({ url: '../server.php',
                    data: {method: 'requestCategories'},
                    type: 'post'
    });
  }`
And then: 
`ajaxRequest = createAJAXRequestToGetCategories();
    ajaxRequest.done(functionToExecute);
functionToExecute(responseData) {
}`

Answer (score 0):

Some differences that come to mind:

1. You cannot use the body in the same way during GET requests, obviously this is not what you are doing above but a lot of requests you are likely seeing are GET requests
2. Debugging, seeing someone hitting `/api.php?action=create.user` and receiving `500`s in your logs is somewhat easier to debug than all of your endpoints under `/api.php`
3. URL character limits, just last week I managed to go over the limit for characters in an endpoint request, i.e. `/api.php?id=1,2,3,4,5...` (general limit is 2083 char), using the body circumvents this to an extent (your server will still limit data posted to an extent)

There may be more, compelling arguments either way. I typically use URL params for purpose/identification- and the body for actual data.